# iOS notification localization failing with FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)

Tags: android, ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using FCM to send localized notifications to both Android and iOS. The flow works and both platforms receive the notification, but on iOS if I try to send a localized key along with arguments the localization fails. If I send a resourceKey with out the need for args it works fine.

**Sample payload request**

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization:key=AAAAR*************aHT" --Header "Content-Type:application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d "{  
   "notification":{  
      "title_loc_key":"titleResourceKey",
      "body_loc_key":"bodyResourceKey",
      "body_loc_args": ["test", "test"]
      "badge":"1",
      "sound":"default"
   },
   "priority":"High",
   "to":   "dqIeO*****relj3k}"
```

**The values in the iOS localizable.strings file.**

```
"titleResourceKey"="title string";
"bodyResourceKey"="s% s% has passed.";
```

**The Values in the android strings.xml file.**

```
  <string formatted="false" name="titleResourceKey">"title string"</string>
  <string formatted="false" name="bodyResourceKey">"s% s% has passed."</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here ended up being caused by the localization plugin I was using in the Framework used to build the application (Nativescript). The strings containing `%s`  needed to be `%@` in iOS.